# Network printer error state at a specific time every day

Tags: network-printer, window-server-2012

We have 2 separated sites with network printers (all different), a VPN server and a Windows Server 2012 in another country on which the printers are connected via the VPN.

Currently, only the `VPN` is in a datacenter with a dedicated IP, the server is behind a `NAT` (so we access it using `RDP` on a specific port), and the `RDP` clients and printers are also behind a `NAT`.

The `VPN` server is actually a `Mikrotik CHR` instance on `Proxmox`, there is a small `Mikrotik` router in our offices on which the printers are connected, and the router gives a static IP to the printers. The `server` is also permanently connected to the `VPN`.

Finally, when a user wants to print a document, he/she connects to the `server` via `RDP`, and prints, and most of the time it prints normally. But what we have noticed is that at precisely 17:00 everyday, no matter which printer we use, they don't print anymore and the state changes from "Printing..." to "Error - Printing...", the printers are on and can be pinged from the server during the errors. I tried restarting the tasks, restarting the Spooler Service, pausing and unpausing the printers...

Is there any way to know the error on windows? Again, what's odd is that it happens around 17:00 everyday (plus or minus 10 min). They usually leave at 17:30 and when they are back the next day, the prints are done. So we don't really know how long it lasts. Sometimes, when I restart many times the task, it ends up disappearing from the queue (as it was printed) but still isn't printed.

Comment: Did it print locally, or just remotly from the rdp session the error is present ?

Comment: Hoping I understand correctly the question, they all work/print from the server via RDP, but the printer is locally installed on the server, using their IP (not shared)